# XARGS, GREP and GNU parallel

Tags: linux, grep, parallel-processing, xargs, io-redirection

Being a linux newbie I am having trouble figuring out some of the elementary aspects of text searching.

What I want to accomplish is as follows:
I have a file with a list of absolutepaths to a particular path.

1. I want to go through this list of files and grep for a particular pattern
2. If the pattern is found in that file, I would like to redirect it to a different output file.
3. Since these files are spread out on the NFS, I would like to speed up the lookup using GNU parallel.

So..what I did was as follows:

```
cat filepaths|xargs -iSomePath echo grep -Pl '\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+' \"SomePath\"> FoundPatternsInFile.out| parallel -v -j 30
```

When I run this command, I am getting the following error repeatedly:

```
grep: "/path/to/file/name": No such file or directory
```

The file and the path exists. Can somebody point out what I might be doing wrong with xargs and grep?

Thanks

Comment: I think I realized what might be happening here, I am enclosing the SomePath variable within quotes. Grep was unable to find the path enclosed within quotes. Removing the quotes and running the command cat filepaths|xargs -iSomePath echo grep -Pl '\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+' SomePath> FoundPatternsInFile.out| parallel -v -j 30 seemed to have solved the issue.

Comment: FYI -- `xargs <filepaths` is a bit more efficient than `cat filepaths | xargs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cat filepaths | parallel -j 30 grep -Pl '\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+' {} > FoundPatternsInFile.out
```

In this case you can even leave out {}.